# Добавление картинок в ImageView через путь, прописанный в Intent

Tags: android, изображения, android-intent, imageview

Столкнулся со следующей ситуацией: у меня активность вызывает другую активность через Intent, добавляя в этот Intent название файла, который вызываемый Intent должен открыть (пусть например это будет p1). Для каждого такого файла p1 существует соответствующее изображение `p1.jpg`, которое должно быть добавлено в ImageView на все той же вызываемой активности. Так вот, возможно ли мне каким-то образом сделать открытие этой картинки более универсальным методом, нежели для каждого файла делать свой `case`, по типу:

```
switch (path){
case "p1":
//добавить p1.jpg 
break;
...
}
```

Comment: нельзя сделать так? path+".jpg"

Comment: @danilshik, да, но изображение добавляется в imageView у меня через         'imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.p1);', а как изменить не знаю

Comment: А почему не передать сразу `id`, а не имя ресурса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из `drawable` по имени достаётся вот так:

`imageView.setImageResource(getResources.getIdentifier(path, "drawable", getPackageName()));`